# Why does this function give an error when run, but not if copied to console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I usually try to avoid posting big messy blocks of code, but I really can't figure out why this script is working fine if I copy it to the console, but if I wrap it all in a function and then call that function, I get the error, animate is not defined.

```
var animation;
var e;
var myPath;
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('svgArea'), 600, 400);
e = paper.circle(106.117, 82.076, 5, 5).attr({
    stroke: "none",
    fill: 'red'
});
var path = 'M106.117,82.076c0,0,227.487-121.053,183.042,22.222c-44.445,143.275-95.322,83.041-95.322,83.041L106.117,82.076z';
myPath = paper.path(path).attr({
    stroke: 'black',
        "stroke-width": 2,
        "stroke-opacity": 0.2
});
animation = setInterval("animate()", 10); //execute the animation function all 10ms (change the value for another speed)
var counter = 0; // a counter that counts animation steps

function animate() {
    if (myPath.getTotalLength() <= counter) { //break as soon as the total length is reached
        counter = 0;
    }
    var pos = myPath.getPointAtLength(counter); //get the position (see Raphael docs)
    e.attr({
        cx: pos.x,
        cy: pos.y
    }); //set the circle position
    counter++; // count the step counter one up
};
```

Comment: If you wrap all that code in a function, then the `animate` function is local to the outer function. `setInterval` will try and look for an `animate` function in the global scope and won't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to @Coin_op's answer is to pass a function reference.

```
animation = setInterval(animate, 10);
```

Comment: Yep, otherwise its an implied eval.

Answer (score 1):

The settimeout call removes the scope from the animate call as you are passing it through as a string. This doesn't matter when animate is global, but once enclosed in a function it does. If you close the animate call inside a function it will still have reference to animate and should work.

```
animation = setInterval(function(){ animate(); }, 10);
```

Comment: `setInterval(animate,10)` is simpler if you don't need to pass any arguments to `animae`

Comment: Fair point, the function wrapper just gives a bit more flexibility.

Comment: The wrapper works if you need to pass parameters - not the case here but worth a note.

Comment: Adding a function wrapper that is not needed encourages copy-paste programming which is a form of cargo cult programming which in my opinion is a bad thing.